# Why does my app keep crashing when I use <View> in android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a fragment that holds a google map.

```
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
            tools:context="com.xxxxx.MapsActivity" />
```

I would like to create a view that is approx 250 x 300 that sits on the map.

Initially I used a ViewFlipper and then a RelativeLayout. That seemed to work but I realised ViewFlipper isn't used for this purpose.

So I changed ViewFlipper to View and RelativeLayout to constraintlayout but the app keeps crashing.

Under the map fragment I have the following:

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp">

         <Button> 
            .....................
            ....................
         </Button>            


        </View>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But after doing a bit of reading is there no simple customisable  component that can be used like in iOS?

Thanks.

Comment: A `<View>` cannot have children. Use one of the `ViewGroup`s; i.e., `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Can constraint layout be used like RelativeLayout, etc.? And if a <View> cannot have children what's it's purpose?

Comment: yes it can be used.

Comment: Inasmuch as it's a `ViewGroup`, sure. But if you just need something like a simple stack of `Button`s, a `LinearLayout` is a lot less overhead. A plain `<View>` in a layout is generally used for spacers, or simple decoration. Apart from that, `View` is the base class for all other UI components.